# iTunes Sync Failed to install - phonegap build

Tags: ios, ipa, phonegap-build

I'm getting this error,
[image]

I'm thinking its something to do with my .p12 and mobiledistrubution file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen these errors when the device's UDID was not part of the distribution (ad hoc) profile.  Did you add this ipad to the distribution profile in itunes connect?

Comment: yeah but i think the certificate may have ran out i was getting alerts but i just ignored them - i'll try that and let you know how it goes.

Comment: ok so it was an issue with my mobile provisioning profile i had to dload and ad hoc one for my ipad - its working now

Comment: That's great.  I updated my answer to include that it is the ad hoc profile.